# Elixir: mongodb update document

Tags: mongodb, elixir

I'm using [Elixir MongoDB driver](https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb). I need to update an existing document. What I'm trying to do:

```
Mongo.find_one_and_update(:mongo, "users", %{user_id: 1}, %{money: 100}, pool: DBConnection.Poolboy)
```

But it throws an error:

> ** (ArgumentError) update only allows atomic modifiers, got: money
>       (mongodb) lib/mongo.ex:788: Mongo.modifier_key/2
>       (mongodb) lib/mongo.ex:173: Mongo.find_one_and_update/5

What is the proper way to update document?
Thank you.

Comment: So you want to set `money` to `100`? Try `%{"$set": %{money: 100}}` instead of `%{money: 100}`.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set fields in an update in MongoDB, you need to put the fields to update in a map with key `:"$set"`:

```
Mongo.find_one_and_update(:mongo, "users", %{user_id: 1}, %{"$set": %{money: 100}}, ...)
```